# on android how to find the original file if got a hard link

Tags: android, filesystems, hardlink

in the app when receiving an intent which was created from other app and has a file path, it can access the file's content using the file path.

the question is if that path (call it as 'link-path') is a 'hard link' to the original file, is it possible to find the original file through this 'link-path'?

Searched and find some post like:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/122333/how-to-tell-which-file-is-original-if-hard-link-is-created

they show some unix shell command. Not sure if there is some android file system support for this, anyone having suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code I made, based on this [post](https://serverfault.com/a/76044). It will return the target path of any path. If path is not a symbolic link, it will return itself. If path doesn't exist it returns null.

```
public static String findLinkTarget(String path) {
    try {
        Process findTarget = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("readlink -f " + path);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(findTarget.getInputStream()));
        return br.readLine();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Couldn't find target file for link: " + path, e);
    }
}
```

The code wasn't tested, but I tested the command on Termux and it worked.

EDIT: Try calling `getCanonicalPath()` on your file, I think it resolves the symlink.

Comment: thanks Nicolas! but it throws java.io.IOException: No such file or directory, Command: [readfile, -f, /data/data/folder1/test.txt] Working Directory: /system Environment: [], after pass the check of:  File file = new File(filePath);
            if (file.exists())

Comment: Ok see my edit it might work. Oh and its my mistake, it ran `readfile` (not a command) instead of `readlink`

Comment: you mean: File file = new File(filePath);
            if (file.exists()) {
                try {
                    String path = file.getCanonicalPath(); ............
                } catch(Exception e){
                    //required by getCanonicalPath, could be ignored here
                } the  file.getCanonicalPath(); is returning the hard l ink, not the original file.

Comment: no, same exception, Error running exec(). Command: [readlink, -f, /data/data/folder1/test.txt] Working Directory: /system Environment: []. My guess maybe the hardlink was created from different app (although it linked to a file in this app).

Comment: ParcelFileDescriptor pfd = ParcelFileDescriptor.open(theFile,ParcelFileDescriptor.parseMode("r"));
StructStat st1 = Os.fstat (pfd.getFileDescriptor ());
st1.st_ino would give the inode info for testing if two files are same inode, but it only works after api 21. How to do it in api <21?

Comment: Try removing the two last arguments in `exec`. If that doesn't work, then I'm clueless...

Comment: doesnot work, after removing the last two params, the Runtime.getRuntime().exec("readlink -f " + path);
         it does not throw but returns the path of the link instead of the original file path. but thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

find a way by comparing the inode, in api >21 android has Os to get it, otherwise using the command "ls -i" to get the inode. One issue though, tested on api<=18 the "ls -i" does not return any thing (tested on emulator), in that case maybe fallback to compare the file's size and timestamp.

```
static String getFileInode(File file) {
    String inode = "-1";
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        StructStat st = null;
        try {
            ParcelFileDescriptor pfd = ParcelFileDescriptor.open(file,
                    ParcelFileDescriptor.parseMode("r"));
            st = Os.fstat (pfd.getFileDescriptor());
            if (st != null) {
                inode = ""+st.st_ino;
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "fstat() failed”+ e.getMessage());
        }
    } else {
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        try {
            Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(("ls -il " + path));
            reader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
            int read;
            char[] buffer = new char[4096];
            StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();
            while ((read = reader.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                output.append(buffer, 0, read);
            }
            process.waitFor();
            String ret = output.toString();
            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(ret)) {
                ret = ret.trim();
                String[] splitArr = ret.split("\\s+");
                if (splitArr.length>0) {
                    inode = splitArr[0];
                }
            }

        } catch(Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "!!! Runtime.getRuntime().exec() exception,  cmd:”+cmd);
        } finally {
           if (reader != null) {
               try {
                   reader.close();
               } catch (IOException e) {}
           }
        }
    }
    return inode;
}
```